# Javascript: import version from package.json

Tags: javascript, version, argparse

Javascript `argparse` package allows to enable `-v, --version` option by default:

```
const parser = new ArgumentParser({
  version: "0.0.1",
  ...
```

I can comment out the `version` attribute, and enter something like this:

```
parser.addArgument(["-V", "--version"], {
  help: "package version",
  action: "version",
  version: "v0.1.0",
});
```

Almost perfect; I'd like to import the version from `package.json`, if possible.

Comment: `version: 'v' + require('./package.json').version`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the version of the app as follows.

```
const packageObj = require('./package.json');
const version = packageObj.version;
```

Comment: Import fails as there is trouble finding `package.json`. Everything installed by `npm` is imported just fine, but `package.json` is just an ordinary file.

Comment: You need to make sure the file `package.json` is in the main folder of your project.

Comment: It's there all right. It is not necessarily the `pwd`, I suppose.